# Problems with using RecyclerView instead of TableLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In an Android application,

I need to set up a page for the user to enter some settings
The settings are 200 different items

I created a `TableLayout` in xml file and each row contains the proper `EditTexts, ImagViews` and ...

The problem is the TableLayout is too large now and creates some performance issues (long processes) and then utilizing `RecyclerView` is suggested to me instead of the TableLayout

The point is the settings are from different types as you can see in the following image:

[image]

So if I have to use RecyclerView then

1 - how can I implement different setting types (which needs different views as is clear in the mentioned image) ?

2 - Since the number of rows is 200 and I've placed the TableLayout inside a ScrollView,
how can I use nested scrolls (one the mentioned ScrollView and the other the RecyclerView scroll) for lower API's (API 14)?

Finally is there a better solution to handle such a case?

Comment: The RecyclerView already knows how to scroll, you won't need to put it in a ScrollView.

Comment: If one recyclerView can handle all different setting types, then yes there is no need but if it is part of the settings, then I need a general ScrollView since there are other settings outside of the RecyclerView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. RecyclerView supports multiple view types, which means you can use different layouts. If all your 200 rows are different, you may need to handle all of them differently. However, you get the performance optimisation from using RecyclerView. You can Google to find more examples or tutorials.
2. It is better to put everything into one RecyclerView instead of putting a RecyclerView inside a ScrollView. That will make you lose the performance bonus from RecyclerView.

Unless someone proposes a better way, using RecyclerView is the best approach that I can think of.

On the other hand, you could probably redesign your UI. For example, having 200 buttons in one page and after click on one of them you go to another screen to do the respective settings.